# Angular conditional class not being added

Tags: angular

Why isn't `test-abc` being added?

```
<div class="abc" [class.test-abc]="true"></div>
```

I used this syntax and it worked:

```
[ngClass]="{'foo': true, 'abc': true}"
```

Comment: Could not replicate; works fine for me.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz showing the issue? See [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezaxnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Hi @matt, your `[class.test-abc]="true"` its also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my notes for this issue. Sometimes change detection does not occur as expected with Angular. Or it does in the controller but does not update your view as expected.

```
<div [ngClass]="{
  'is-active': condition,
  'is-inactive': !condition,
  'is-focused': condition && anotherCondition,
}">
```

or toggling from the view

```
<a (click)="clicked ? clicked = false : clicked = true;" [class.active]="clicked">organize</a>
```

Try logging your variable in on changes to see if it is in fact updating:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if ('variable' in changes) {
        console.log(this.variable);
    }
}
```

Comment: the second one is the same as mine

Comment: change detection isn't an issue i'm only using [class.abc]="true" no variables

Comment: The brackets tell Angular that the expression should be [evaluated](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets). `true` will be evaluated as `true`.